# Parse an object to a string representation c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to parse my variable to its string representation `typeName`.

```
string typeName = property.PropertyType.ToString();
var propertyItem = (typeName)property.GetValue(templateData, null);
```

The string `typeName` should be the 'Type' of the property I have in my Model so somehow i want to parse it to that type. (at this moment it is `List(InvoiceModel)`, but this may vary)

I hope this is enough information, otherwise please notify me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't do what it looks like you're implying in the second line of your code, as types *must* be known at compile time.  The closest you can get is to use `object` or (if you must be able to access arbitrary methods or properties) `dynamic`.

Comment: this entire concept is very dangerous, unless you have literally no other choice (and if you do have no choice your initial plan is most likely wrong) don't do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`property.GetValue` returns the required object. From your code sample it seems that you don't know the object's type at compile time.

It is not possible to cast that object using `(typename)`, and there is no use, because still you won't know the real type at compile time.

What you probably want to do is to use `dynamic`:

```
dynamic propertyItem = property.GetValue(templateData, null);
```

Comment: yep, that was what I needed.. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is property.GetType().ToString();

though you can't just put the varable in brackets to convert you need to use reflection to create the type

That said this entire idea is a bad idea, from the look of your code i think your trying to create some form of MetaData, if so then i would use an Enum to define your allowed datatypes, and i would only allow the simplest ones int, double, string, datetime etc and possibly an array's of such

in that case you would then do,

```
if(Property.Type == AllowedTyoes.String)
{
    string stringval = Property.Value as string;
    //use the string for a string safe function
}
if(Property.Type == AllowedTyoes.Int)
{
    string stringval = Property.Value as string;
    int tmp;
    if(int.TryParse(stringval,out tmp))
    {
        //use the int for a int safe function
    }
}
```